# Compilation errors after ROS update (ros/datatypes.h missing?)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since today I am receiving the following error when trying to compile my packages. No changes were made to my packages and they compiled just fine last week. I did update Ubuntu and ROS over the weekend.

```
/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/serialization.h:40:27: fatal error: ros/datatypes.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and ROS Hydro.

Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122686/compilation-errors-after-ros-update-(ros/datatypes.h-missing?)/) by [rolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/10826/rolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I had the same problem a week ago.

Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Let me know if this works.

Another problem (if you plan to use kinect) I had with Ubuntu 13.04 was with the openni libraries. I needed to go back to the 12.04. Regards

---

Originally posted by [lfelipesv](https://answers.ros.org/users/10721/lfelipesv/) with karma: 58 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/10826/rolf/) on 2014-01-27**:
Thanks! These commands gave me some useful error messages which I could resolve! :)
Apparently some dependencies on my machine were messed up. I ended up reinstalling most of ros-hydro which worked.